# Respond correctly to CORS OPTIONS preflight requests to the API

Tags: feature-request, api

When developing against the API, in particular for userscript purposes, I've been running up against an issue: the API doesn't respond correctly to CORS preflight requests.

A [CORS preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) is a separate HTTP request issued before the main CORS request, to verify that the server supports the requested methods, headers, and origin (using `Access-Control-Request-*` headers; the server responds with `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers). It uses the HTTP `OPTIONS` method.

This is an issue for the SE API, because if you call the API using any other type of request than what the documentation specifies, you get a 400 Bad Request error, with the following response:

```
{
  "error_id": 404,
  "error_message": "this method cannot be called this way",
  "error_name":"no_method"
}
```

Specifically, I'm seeing this on requests to the `/posts/:ids` endpoint.

Can the API respond to these requests correctly?